# Represent torch.einsum as torch.matmul operation

Tags: pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to implement an einsum operation as matrix multiplication in pytorch. In the example below,
*degree_matrix_hat* is a matrix with shape (64, 115) and *edge_features_reduced* is a tensor of shape (64, 115, 115).

Using torch.einsum I get the following output:

```
ein1 = torch.einsum("bi,bij->bij",degree_matrix_hat, edge_features_reduced)
ein1[0],ein1.size()
(tensor([[0.7071, 0.7071, 0.0000,  ..., 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.5774, 0.5774, 0.5774,  ..., 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.5774, 0.5774,  ..., 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         ...,
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000]]),
 torch.Size([64, 115, 115]))
```

However, I get a different output using using torch.matmul:

```
matmul1=torch.matmul(degree_matrix_hat, edge_features_reduced)
matmul1[0],matmul1.size()
(tensor([[1.2845, 1.8618, 1.7321,  ..., 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],
         [1.2845, 1.7845, 1.6547,  ..., 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],
         [1.2071, 1.7845, 1.6547,  ..., 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],
         ...,
         [1.2071, 1.7845, 1.6547,  ..., 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],
         [1.2845, 1.7845, 1.6547,  ..., 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],
         [1.2071, 1.7845, 1.6547,  ..., 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000]]),
 torch.Size([64, 64, 115]))
```

I'm quite new to linear algebra so I probably missed something here. What is the exact expression torch.einsum is solving in this case?

Comment: That `einsum` signature isn't computing a `matmul` operation but broadcasted element-wise multiplication `degree_matrix_hat[...,None] * edge_features_reduced`. Repeated axis on the left side of the signature will be element-wise multiplied.